# Narrowing Union Type of Set and Array for find method

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, set, union-types

I have the following Data model

Daily Data of a person

```
interface FetchDocument {
    Date : number,
    Hours : number,
}
```

A collection of those data

```
type Data_Array = Set<FetchDocument> | FetchDocument[]

interface GroupDocument {
    name : string,
    Data : Data_Array,
   
}
```

A sample data for test is as follows

```
let fetchArray : GroupDocument[] = [
    {
        name : 'John',
        Data : [
            {
                Date : 13,
                'Hours' : 14
            },
            {
                Date : 12,
                'Hours' : 433
            }
        ] 
    }
]
```

When I want to find on that sample using find method

```
for(let i= 0; i < fetchArray.length ; i++){
    let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
}
```

The compiler is complaining as below because of Set Type on Data_Array.

> error TS2339: Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Data_Array'.
>
> > Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Set'.

So what I have tried is try to narrow or re-assign to solve in three ways

Narrowing

```
 if(Array.isArray(fetchArray[i].Data)){
        let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
 }
```

```
 if(typeof(fetchArray[i].Data.find) === 'function'){
        let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
    }
```

```
   if(fetchArray[i].Data instanceof Array){
        let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
    }
```

Re-assigning to array

```
fetchArray[i].Data = [...fetchArray[i].Data] 
let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
```

```
fetchArray[i].Data = Array.from(fetchArray[i].Data.values())
let obj = fetchArray[i].Data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
```

But the error can't be solved so what can I do to resolve it.

Playground link : [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

*Set is used when fetching data to detect duplicate data so changing it will cause for changing code on other part of codebase*

Comment: Why would you reassign the variable a set? Just keep it an array.

Comment: I need to work this variable as a set prior this code, to detect duplicate data when fetching from api. so yeah, if there is no solution, I would need to change it only as an array type I guess.

Comment: If it is **initially a set**, then why would you **reassign it to an array**? Just make another variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due what we call `Temporal Uncertainty`. Typescript doesn't know if there's any other codes changing the content of `fetchArray` that could lead to a different value while executing the code.

There is no need to explicit type assertion whatsoever, just save the value you wanna check in another variable as soon as you validate it

```js
for (let i = 0; i < fetchArray.length; i++){
    let arr = fetchArray[i].Data;
    if (arr instanceof Array) {
        let obj = arr.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date === 13)
    }
}
```

Comment: Urgh thats why, thanks for explaining dude. This will help me a lot on writing typescript in the future.

Comment: yes. due to more accurate and conclusiveness, I will set this as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use [`Type Assertions`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in this case, but if the data is not an array, it will cause errors during `runtime` that's why you should also be careful about `runtime errors`.

Here is how you can do this,

```
for(let i= 0; i < fetchArray.length ; i++){
    // treat data as a FetchDocument[] type note! it can be another type on run time
    const data = fetchArray[i].Data as FetchDocument[] 
    // consider use error handling here
    let obj = data.find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
}
```

[**Demo**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITAgFgEQPYICuAthOMgN4BQytyOckyAXMiCQEbQA0NdAEnkJQAzizaceVAL50qVMAE8ADigZg4AfQCCUKHEXIAvMgDKGADzpMuAiTJgAfMgA+aDNnxFS4ANoBdeVBIWEQUAHEoIWUve3JqOjY4UnERMChQAHNeRPU4cTydPQMc2hl5ABsMZBgPLF19Q1ZI6NifMADjZF8+WgTEuhBklFYAcgApPCwQUdKB+kZ81h75+f7V1fUR5ABGAGY5jYHRwWERUfEdgBZeo+lDjfWj3MZtnYAmB+fkE6FRC9YVz2e1uG2koLo-mQt3BgSoMDwUAAFFUwMhgCYAAwAbnRyAsNTqDQMADoqiBMmAsMhccAANR0gCUTwQeBAaWQABNFl1ajZiYpfMB-CS8sg4GJrJ47O0ArdUcg8BwAFZdbkaEkwUCcpFIpWq1hS2zeByM4zOfWi17GIwmXZ7ZCM8pUIA)

### Updated

You can also use `Array.from` method without adding any extra `if`

```
for(let i= 0; i < fetchArray.length ; i++){
    let obj = Array.from (fetchArray[i].Data)
     .find((obj : FetchDocument) => obj.Date ===  13 )
}
```